# Xamarin - restore packages failed after migrating to AndroidX

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, androidx

after migrating to AnroidX I got restore failed

```
Version conflict detected for Xamarin.Android.Support.v4. Install/reference Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 28.0.0.1 directly to project Pyx.Mobile.Android to resolve this issue. 
 Pyx.Mobile.Android -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location 71.1600.0 -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement 71.1620.0 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (>= 28.0.0.1) 
 Pyx.Mobile.Android -> Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client 4.1.2 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs 23.3.0 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.3.0).
Restore failed.
```

my packages

```
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V4">
      <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.Android.Material">
      <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat">
      <Version>1.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.CardView">
      <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.MediaRouter">
      <Version>1.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials">
      <Version>1.5.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.ExifInterface">
      <Version>1.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration" Version="1.0.0" />  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V4">
    <Version>1.0.0-preview02</Version>
  </PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration" Version="1.0.0-preview03" /></ItemGroup>
```

what I am missing ??

Comment: the error message tells you **exactly** what to do - "Install/reference Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 28.0.0.1 directly to project Pyx.Mobile.Android to resolve this issue.'

Comment: yea I know and this will make it fixed but I think we should do that as we already have Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V4 installed so I wonder what to do

Comment: which API do you target? AndroidX is for Android Q - API29

Comment: yes I am targeting Android Q - API29

Comment: This `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement` the nuget packages depend on the `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (>= 28.0.0.1)`, So you have to install it. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement/

Comment: so no replacement with Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V4

Comment: wait for an update of the component that supports AndroidX

Comment: yea I think its the right answer

Comment: there is already an [AndroidX branch on github](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/tree/master_based_androidx/), so it should be released soon

Comment: I'm confused. I'm having similar issues, but since I'm targeting androidQ, I cannot reference the old support library directly, since it is only compatible up to android P. How can I resolve these kind of conflicts?